# Computing covariance matrix and mean in python for a Gaussian Mixture Model

Tags: covariance, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I am studying Bishop's PRML book and trying to implement Gaussian Mixture Model from scratch in python.

So I have prepared a synthetic dataset which is divided into 2 classes using the following code.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.title("Two blobs", fontsize='small')

X, Y = make_blobs(n_features=2, centers=2)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], marker='o', c=Y)
plt.show()
```

Which gives the output,

[image: scatterplt]

Now I want to apply GMM to classify the data.

The responsibility is defined as

$$
\gamma(z_{nk}) = \frac{\pi_{k} \mathcal{N} (x_{n} | \mu_{k}, \Sigma_{k})  } {\sum_{j=1}^{K} \pi_{j} \mathcal{N}(x_{n} | \mu_{j}, \Sigma_{j}) } 
$$

So here are the things I've understood from reading the chapter,

$\pi_{k}$ is the mixing coefficient where, $\sum_{k=1}^{K}\pi_{k} = 1$, if I have two classes $(K=2)$ then $\pi_{1} + \pi_{2} = 1$, $n$ is the number of data (rows) which in my case is $100$.

Since my input data looks like this,

```
X[:5]

# Output

array([[ 10.79935045,   1.64540763],
       [ -0.59652355,   0.7210502 ],
       [  1.62648065,   0.43254009],
       [  8.28627001,   0.58049497],
       [  8.78623998,   1.41660207]])
```

Suppose I want to pick the first row from the input data, as `X[0] = [ 10.79935045,   1.64540763]` and let's assume it belongs to the class $1$.

I calculated the covariance matrix $\Sigma_{1}$  and mean $\mu_{1}$ using this code,

```
print("Covariance: {}".format(np.cov(X[0])))
print("Mean: {}".format(np.mean(X[0], axis=0)))

# Covariance: 41.89733463605499
# Mean: 6.222379038791568
```

Did I understand and calculated everything properly? Please correct me if I'm wrong, any supporting codes or explanation would be really helpful. Thanks.

*Edit:*

I think $\mu_{k}$ and $\Sigma_{k}$ should be calculated from all of the rows from corresponding classes, but not from a single row. I've done that using this code

```
x_class_1 = np.array([list(X[i]) for i in range(len(X)) if Y[i] == 0])
np.cov(x_class_1)
```

Which gives a $50\times 50$ covariance matrix. Assuming that's correct, how can I compute the mean?

I did a bit study, and I think I'm going the wrong way. Since there are two features in my dataset, the rank of the covariance matrix must be $2$.